# Sync Adapter not calling onCreate

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-syncadapter

Do we need to start the Sync Adapter service or framework starts implicitly? I have put a log on `Constructor`, `onCreate`, `onDestroy` of Sync Adapter service and when I start the app, I don't see the logs in the logcat.

But when I do on activity `onCreate`

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, SyncService.class);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

I see the logs.

Please suggests.

Cheers,
Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync adapter starts explicitly by calling:

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(ACCOUNT, AUTHORITY, null);
```

or similar method:

```
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(
            ACCOUNT,
            AUTHORITY,
            Bundle.EMPTY,
            SYNC_INTERVAL);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html

I strongly recommend this book, especially first 200 pages http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Enterprise-Android-Programming-Android-Database-Applications-for-the-Enterprise.productCd-1118183495.html .